# twitter bootstrap select silviomoreto increase height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, height

I´m using twitter bootstrap select component from silviomoreto. I´m just trying to style the field by increasing the height to 45px.

While in other bootstrap input components I have no problem, it is not working in this select component.

Comment: Some code would help, your CSS/HTML, a demo site or JS Fiddle ideally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apply this css:

```
.bootstrap-select > .btn {
    height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Silvio, I have this component in the home view. When I load it for first time it works perfect. But, when I go to some other view and I click home again, them the component lose the style again. If I reload the view with F5 it gets the style again. I use this to link to home <a href="/">Home</a>.

Comment: well, that is strange... Did you check if the javascript is properly called?

Comment: I guess its properly called when it´s working for first time, right?

Comment: Idk, probably not. Try to apply `$('select').setStyle('warning', 'add')`. If it keeps happening, please provide more info, like your code or a jsfiddle